# Is this an error...?

Tags: grammar, parsing, sound-symbolism

I came across the following in a book I'm reading but have ever seen that kind of grammar before, and Google isn't bringing anything up at all:

固くし**てみあ**

I'm beginning to think it's a print error.
If anyone will know it'll be you guys on here :)

P.S. the full sentence was:
そのとき、腕の中でしどけなく溶けていた猫が急に身を固くしてみあ、と鳴いて。

Answer (score 7):

`みあ` stands for meow, the sound tone of the cat.

> そのとき、腕の中でしどけなく溶けていた猫が急に身を固くしてみあ、と鳴いて。

The whole sentence means

> Suddenly, the cat, which was just lying liquidly in man's arm, quickly
>   restored its body, and "meow"-ed out.

(forgive my poor translation -w-||)

Comment: I was starting to think it was some kind of てみる form that I'd never seen before. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 4):

It's not a typo. This みあ should be a variation of みゃあ or にゃあ ("meow"), and と is a quotative particle. It will be read like:

> 猫が急に身を固くして、
>   The cat suddenly went rigid,
>
> 「みあ」と鳴いて。
>   and said "meow".

Comment: Ah yep - Jisho has にゃあ (but not みあ nor みゃあ for some reason).
Thanks!